# Почему не работает функция закрытия формы?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой файл `js`

```
function access (){
        while (prompt ('Введите пароль для доступа к странице:') !='11111'){
            if(confirm ('Пароль неверный. Повторить ввод?')==false){
                    window.location.href ='error.html';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

       function newForm(){

        var x, y;
        var win; 

        x = (window.outerWidth - 300) / 2 + window.screenX;
        y = (window.outerHeight - 200) / 2 + window.screenY;

        win = window.open("", "w1", "height = 200, width = 300 , left ="+ x +" ,top =" +y);
        win.document.write("<h2>Заголовок текста</h2>");
        win.document.write("<p>javascript — это круто!</p>");

        win.document.write('<p align = "center"><input type="button" onclick="opener.exit(opener.win);" name="closeButton" value="Закрыть"></input></p>');

    }

        function exit (param){
        param.alert('Внимание окно будет закрыто!');
        param.close();
    }
```

Я подключил его к странице и обнаружил, что на форме, созданной с помощью `newForm()` не работает кнопка "Закрыть", хотя я сделал все так, как указано в примере:

> Для кнопки на дочерней форме также нужно вызвать созданную функцию.
>   При этом нужно учитывать следующие особенности:
>   - функция описана на главной форме, следовательно для доступа к ней нужно использовать стандартное имя родительского окна opener. Функция
>   имеет имя opener.exit;
>   - в качестве параметра функции нужно указать глобальную переменную win, в которой хранится ссылка на дочернее окно. Так как эта
>   переменная описана на главной форме, то для доступа к ней используем
>   имя opener.win.

Далее там идет код функции `newForm()`. Почему не работает кнопка?

Comment: какого года, интересно, этот код

Comment: @humster_spb пока учу основы js. Дальше не будет все так страшно)) Но нужно в этом коде разобраться, так как работа с родительским окном и все такое))